# PHP - strtotime returning 3 digits too short?

Tags: php, datetime

I have a simple piece of PHP ode at the moment:

```
echo strtotime("2011-06-26T10:00:36+10:00");
```

Which is returning:

```
1309046436
```

If I run the equivalent via JavaScript:

```
new Date("2011-06-26T10:00:36+10:00").valueOf();
```

I get the following:

```
1309046436000
```

As you can see the PHP version is returning 3 digits too short. Do you know what the problem is? Is it a memory issue?

Comment: One is seconds, the other milliseconds. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: In PHP you get seconds, in Javascript milliseconds. Just divide or multiply by 1000.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I missed an obvious detail (duh).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP uses seconds. JavaScript uses milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

php returns seconds,

while javascript returns milliseconds.